# Intellisense Errors and #I with Script Files

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012

Are there any known issues with Intellisense and the use of #I combined with #r when using script files?

What I am noticing is that if I reference an assembly using #r and the full path I get intellisense.

If I make use of #I to add to my path than use #r without the full path to the assembly I get no intellisense for types in that assembly.

Is this a known issue?

Edit:

Here is the example.

This doesn't give Intellisense but runs.

```
#I @"C:\PathToAssembly"
#r "MyAssembly.dll"

open Some.NameSpace //<-- gives errors in intellisense (module not found)
                    // runs just fine when sending to fsi
```

Next example where everythign works fine.

```
#r @"C:\PathToAssembly\MyAssembly.dll"

open Some.NameSpace <-- no error in intellisense.
```

Comment: Can you give an example? It's more likely you're referring to a wrong path.

Comment: I will. But basically I am referencing a custom assembly. 

If I use #I and the full path than #r for just the dll.  I can run everything but I get no intellisense. 

If I use #r with full path I can run and get intellisense.

Comment: I've hit this issue while trying to edit Fake scripts, but it is depressingly intermittent. Basically, it's exactly what davewolfs says: normally you get intellisense whether or use #l and #r or a full path in #r. But sometimes when you use #l you don't. Even if it was working a few minutes earlier...

Comment: @pad I've added an example.  Seems consistent at least on VS 2012.

Comment: @davewolfs: I can reproduce the behaviour. You should send a report to fsbugs (at) microsoft (dot) com with a simple repro.

Answer (score 0):

There's a case in MS Connect that seems to be this same issue:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733523/f-3-0-beta-intellisense-issues-of-interactive-enviroment

It's been closed as Not Reproducible, however the original creator posted some details in the Workaround section suggesting it was caused by having an FSharp.Core DLL in the same folder.

Is it possible you also have an FSharp.Core in this folder? If so; deleting it and letting it come from the GAC might solve the issue (though it still sounds like a bug to me).